# FactoryGirl multiple different users

Tags: ruby

how can i define multiple users with different fields with FactoryGirl for testing my app with different permissions? when my permissions are defined by field is_admin on same user table

Comment: Do you just need the FactoryGirl _syntax_ to define DB objects? If so, what do you have already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example if we are defining like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
factory :user do |f|
...
end
end
```

just modify to:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
factory :user, class: User do |f|
...
end
factory :admin, class: User do |f|
...
end
factory :editor, class: User do |f|
...
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use inheritance if most of the fields are common:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name { Faker::Name.name }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }

    factory :editor do
      is_admin { false }
    end

    factory :admin do
      is_admin { true }
    end
  end
end
```

For more information and examples see the documentation: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md